# Create three array from other array

Tags: php

I have an array something like below.We need to create three array from this array.We need to seperate all for facebook inside another array and something like other twitter,email.

Is this possible?

```
Array
(
    [01] => Array
        (
            [facebook] => 375
            [twitter] => 3276
            [email] => 3276
        )

    [02] => Array
        (
            [facebook] => 385
            [twitter] => 3326
            [email] => 3326
        )

    [03] => Array
        (
            [facebook] => 391
            [twitter] => 3327
            [email] => 3327
        )

    [04] => Array
        (
            [facebook] => 446
            [twitter] => 3327
            [email] => 3327
        )

    [05] => Array
        (
            [facebook] => 486
            [twitter] => 3334
            [email] => 3334
        )

    [06] => Array
        (
            [facebook] => 2
            [twitter] => 6
            [email] => 6
        )

    [07] => Array
        (
            [facebook] => 1
            [twitter] => 7
            [email] => 7
        )

    [08] => Array
        (
            [facebook] => 3
            [twitter] => 11
            [email] => 11
        )

    [09] => Array
        (
            [facebook] => 0
            [twitter] => 0
            [email] => 0
        )

    [10] => Array
        (
            [facebook] => 0
            [twitter] => 0
            [email] => 0
        )

    [11] => Array
        (
            [facebook] => 0
            [twitter] => 0
            [email] => 0
        )

    [12] => Array
        (
            [facebook] => 0
            [twitter] => 0
            [email] => 0
        )

)
```

We need like this for all three(facebook,twitter,email)

```
Array(
    [01]=>385,
    [02]=>375,
    [03]=>391,
    [04]=>446,
    [05]=>486,
    [06]=>2,
    [07]=>1,
    [08]=>0,
    [09]=>0,
    [10]=>0,
    [11]=>0,
    [12]=>0,
}
```

Comment: Yes, it is possible. What have you tried? `foreach` seems like a good start.

Comment: OK, what is your question?

Comment: Um, ok. Have you tried anything?

Comment: How it is possible?.I am confused where we start.

Comment: Use a `foreach` loop.

Answer (score 2):

```
$your_array = //here you have your original array

$facebook = array();
$twitter = array();
$email = array();

foreach($your_array as $sub_array) {
 $facebook[] = $sub_array["facebook"];
 $twitter[] = $sub_array["twitter"];
 $email[] = $sub_array["email"];
}
```

Comment: Hell you spoiled it, we wanted him to at least try :(

Answer (score 1):

Try [array_column](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php)

```
$fb=array_column($array, 'facebook');
```

OR

```
$fb=array_map( function ($i) { return $i['facebook'];},$array);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create three arrays easily :-)
   let say main array name is $mainarray

```
    $facebookarr = array();
    $twitterarr = array();
    $emailarr = array();
    foreach($mainarray as $socialarray)
    {
      $facebookarr[]  =  $socialarray['facebook'];
      $twitterarr[] =   $socialarray['twitter']
      $emailarr[] =     $socialarray['email']
    }
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($facebookarr);
    print_r($twitterarr);
    print_r($emailarr);
```